# C# - Use of compute shaders

Tags: c#, directx-11, compute-shader

I'm trying to implement, using SharpDX11, a ray/mesh intersection method using the GPU. I've seen from an older post ([Older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40184304/directx-11-compute-shader-for-ray-mesh-intersect/49908093#49908093)) that this can be done using the Compute Shader; but I need help in order to create and define the buffer outside the .hlsl code.

My HLSL code is the following:

```
struct rayHit
{
     float3 intersection;
};

cbuffer cbRaySettings : register(b0)
{
    float3 rayFrom;
    float3 rayDir;
    uint TriangleCount;
};

StructuredBuffer<float3> positionBuffer : register(t0);
StructuredBuffer<uint3> indexBuffer : register(t1);

AppendStructuredBuffer<rayHit> appendRayHitBuffer : register(u0);

void TestTriangle(float3 p1, float3 p2, float3 p3, out bool hit, out float3 intersection)
{
//Perform ray/triangle intersection
//Compute vectors along two edges of the triangle.
float3 edge1, edge2;
float distance;

//Edge 1
edge1.x = p2.x - p1.x;
edge1.y = p2.y - p1.y;
edge1.z = p2.z - p1.z;

//Edge2
edge2.x = p3.x - p1.x;
edge2.y = p3.y - p1.y;
edge2.z = p3.z - p1.z;

//Cross product of ray direction and edge2 - first part of determinant.
float3 directioncrossedge2;
directioncrossedge2.x = (rayDir.y * edge2.z) - (rayDir.z * edge2.y);
directioncrossedge2.y = (rayDir.z * edge2.x) - (rayDir.x * edge2.z);
directioncrossedge2.z = (rayDir.x * edge2.y) - (rayDir.y * edge2.x);

//Compute the determinant.
float determinant;
//Dot product of edge1 and the first part of determinant.
determinant = (edge1.x * directioncrossedge2.x) + (edge1.y * directioncrossedge2.y) + (edge1.z * directioncrossedge2.z);

//If the ray is parallel to the triangle plane, there is no collision.
//This also means that we are not culling, the ray may hit both the
//back and the front of the triangle.
if (determinant == 0)
{
    distance = 0.0f;
    intersection = float3(0, 0, 0);
    hit = false;
}

float inversedeterminant = 1.0f / determinant;

//Calculate the U parameter of the intersection point.
float3 distanceVector;
distanceVector.x = rayFrom.x - p1.x;
distanceVector.y = rayFrom.y - p1.y;
distanceVector.z = rayFrom.z - p1.z;

float triangleU;
triangleU = (distanceVector.x * directioncrossedge2.x) + (distanceVector.y * directioncrossedge2.y) + (distanceVector.z * directioncrossedge2.z);
triangleU = triangleU * inversedeterminant;

//Make sure it is inside the triangle.
if (triangleU < 0.0f || triangleU > 1.0f)
{
    distance = 0.0f;
    intersection = float3(0, 0, 0);
    hit = false;
}

//Calculate the V parameter of the intersection point.
float3 distancecrossedge1;
distancecrossedge1.x = (distanceVector.y * edge1.z) - (distanceVector.z * edge1.y);
distancecrossedge1.y = (distanceVector.z * edge1.x) - (distanceVector.x * edge1.z);
distancecrossedge1.z = (distanceVector.x * edge1.y) - (distanceVector.y * edge1.x);

float triangleV;
triangleV = ((rayDir.x * distancecrossedge1.x) + (rayDir.y * distancecrossedge1.y)) + (rayDir.z * distancecrossedge1.z);
triangleV = triangleV * inversedeterminant;

//Make sure it is inside the triangle.
if (triangleV < 0.0f || triangleU + triangleV > 1.0f)
{
    distance = 0.0f;
    intersection = float3(0, 0, 0);
    hit = false;
}

//Compute the distance along the ray to the triangle.
float raydistance;
raydistance = (edge2.x * distancecrossedge1.x) + (edge2.y * distancecrossedge1.y) + (edge2.z * distancecrossedge1.z);
raydistance = raydistance * inversedeterminant;

//Is the triangle behind the ray origin?
if (raydistance < 0.0f)
{
    distance = 0.0f;
    intersection = float3(0, 0, 0);
    hit = false;
}

intersection = rayFrom + (rayDir * distance);
hit = true;
}

[numthreads(64, 1, 1)]
void CS_RayAppend(uint3 tid : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
if (tid.x >= TriangleCount)
    return;

uint3 indices = indexBuffer[tid.x];
float3 p1 = positionBuffer[indices.x];
float3 p2 = positionBuffer[indices.y];
float3 p3 = positionBuffer[indices.z];

bool hit;
float3 p;
TestTriangle(p1, p2, p3, hit, p);

if (hit)
{
    rayHit hitData;
    hitData.intersection = p;
    appendRayHitBuffer.Append(hitData);
}
}
```

While the following is part of my c# implementation but I'm not able to understand how lo load buffers for compute shader.

```
int count = obj.Mesh.Triangles.Count;
        int size = 8; //int+float for every hit
        BufferDescription bufferDesc = new BufferDescription() {
            BindFlags = BindFlags.UnorderedAccess | BindFlags.ShaderResource,
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
            OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.BufferStructured,
            StructureByteStride = size,
            SizeInBytes = size * count
        };
        Buffer buffer = new Buffer(device, bufferDesc);
        UnorderedAccessViewDescription uavDescription = new UnorderedAccessViewDescription() {
            Buffer = new UnorderedAccessViewDescription.BufferResource() { FirstElement = 0, Flags = UnorderedAccessViewBufferFlags.None, ElementCount = count },
            Format = SharpDX.DXGI.Format.Unknown,
            Dimension = UnorderedAccessViewDimension.Buffer
        };
        UnorderedAccessView uav = new UnorderedAccessView(device, buffer, uavDescription);
        context.ComputeShader.SetUnorderedAccessView(0, uav);

        var code = HLSLCompiler.CompileFromFile(@"Shaders\TestTriangle.hlsl", "CS_RayAppend", "cs_5_0");
        ComputeShader _shader = new ComputeShader(device, code);
        Buffer positionsBuffer = new Buffer(device, Utilities.SizeOf<Vector3>(), ResourceUsage.Default, BindFlags.None, CpuAccessFlags.None, ResourceOptionFlags.None, 0);
        context.UpdateSubresource(ref data, positionsBuffer);
        context.ComputeShader.Set(_shader);
```

Inside my c# implementation i'm considering only one ray (with its origin and direction) and I would like to use the shader to check the intersection with all the triangles of the mesh. I'm already able to do that using the CPU but for 20k+ triangles the computation took too long even if i'm already using parallel coding.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Don't hesitate to share your attempt

Comment: Yep, sorry. I've edited my answer with my wrong current attempt